# Generate Table rows from template

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

i want to generate table rows from template in Mediawiki:

I have a main table, where a custom number of elements (are inputted by a form by the user.
The **input form** looks like:

`{for template|Team|multiple|embed in field=Project[Team]}`

and generates

```
{{Project
|Team={{Team|Role|First Name}}{{Team|Role2|Second Name}}
}}
```

The **Template "Team"** gives back formatted mediawiki table rows:

```
|{{{1}}} 
|{{#arraymap:{{{2}}}|,|x|[[x]]|,&#32;}}
|-
```

And are embedded in the **Main-Table-Template**:

```
{|
! Team
|-
{{#if: {{Team}}|{{{Team}}} }}
|}
```

But unfortunately this gives a warning: "The Value of the attribute Team "|Role1..." contains invalid characters or is incomplete..." (translated from german).

I tried replacing `|` & `|-` with the recommended `{{!}}` but had no success.
Hope someone has an idea to remove those warning